# PowerShell if elseif else

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Wondering if anyone could please assist with below.

I've tried a few different ways to get the below code working. Have three possible outcomes.

1. UM enabled with 5 digit extension.
2. UM enabled with no 5 digit extension.
3. UM not enabled.

```
          #test for UM extension number#
          $um1 = Get-UmMailbox $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select @{name=”Extensions”;expression={$_.Extensions -join “;”}} | ?{ $_.Extensions -match '^\d\d\d\d\d$' }
          $umextensionnumber = if ($um1) { $um1.Extensions } elseif (!$um1) { 'UM not enabled' } else { 'No UM Extension Number' }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Way easier to read (and reason about) with nested `if`'s instead:

```
$umextensionnumber = if($um1){
  # UM is enabled, let's check the extension:
  if($um1.Extensions -match '\d\d\d\d\d'){
    $um1.Extensions
  }
  else {
    "No extension found"
  }
}
else {
  "UM not enabled"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I see the logic in the nested if's that is something I will remember. What are your thoughts on extracting only the 5 digit number to output? Extensions property looks like this {user@domain.com, 12345} or {12345} I can only get output for latter, former ends up outputting No Extension Found.

Comment: `-match` doubles as a filter operator, so simply output `@($um1.Extensions) -match '\d\d\d\d\d'` and it'll result in only `"12345"`